# How to get previous and next records In Mysql.

Tags: mysql

Today When i working with mysql i get a problem related to previous and next records.

[image]

My Problem is when i was trying to get next record of Id 572491.
As per requirement it should be 572506 but i am get records .

[image]

What i do for these result

```
Article Id  Public Date
572506      2011-01-17 15:45:00
```

Comment: sort by id, that would be the latest records... may be mid ones are deleted..so better sort them with id and see if they exist there or not

Comment: Please provided the expected out put since from the question it appears that you want to get the next record after a specif id.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Plz check the first Image here ID 572491,572506 and 572508 are one by one.  I want the next ID 572506 by second query

Comment: Yes my answer should return `572506` when you compare with  `572491`

Comment: Please edit your question and put in the query you are using, sample data and desired results.  The screen images are very difficult to read.

Comment: Trust Gordon please, we can't barely read it

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a2.article_id, a2.public_date FROM articles as a LEFT JOIN article_images AS ai ON a.article_id = ai.article INNER JOIN articles as a2 ON a.article_id = a2.article_id AND a.article_id > 572491 WHERE ai.pathname!='' AND a.status=3 GROUP BY a2.article_id ORDER BY a.public_date ASC
```

This would sort your list by date all results and then filter based on id > 572491